# Vague preference?

Tags: adjectives

I wanted to say that I vaguely prefer math and science over language classes. Does it sound weird if I said

"I have a vague preference of math and science over other academic subjects."

Comment: Most people talk about [*a **slight** preference **for** X*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+vague+preference%2Ca+slight+preference&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20vague%20preference%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20slight%20preference%3B%2Cc0) rather than a ***vague*** one. Especially if it's your ***own*** preference (since ***vague*** means "uncertain, indefinite, unclear", and in principle you ought to know your own preferences better than that). But no-one else is likely to be so picky as me. In short, you can say that if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment, that the word **slight** would usually be chosen over **vague**, but the intended meaning is still completely clear, so it's fine.

However - vague or slight - I would only have preferences **for** something over something else, not **of** it.

Answer (score 0):

Added to the two other comments, I think 'vaguely' can have a negative connotation, whereas 'slightly' generally can't (the way I see it, it's indecision versus nuance).

If this is for some application, and particularly if it's for a science-related one, I would omit the adverb altogether, or say something along the lines of 'I like both, science in particular'.